# Add a Total row after each week

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am searching for a way to sum columns by week.
This is the initial table data.

```
Date            WeekNo      Col1        Col2        Col3
2020/07/01      27           1           4          3
2020/07/04      27           3           3          1
2020/07/06      28           1           1          1
2020/07/11      28           1           3          8
```

and I want to add a row total to every end of the week like this:

```
Date            WeekNo      Col1        Col2        Col3
2020/07/01      27           1           4          3
2020/07/04      27           3           3          1
TOTAL           27           4           7          4
2020/07/06      28           1           1          1
2020/07/11      28           1           3          8
TOTAL           28           2           4          9
```

I tried something similar the the code below but I have multiple columns to sum.
Do you have other ideas, suggestions?

Also, grouping sets does not create a new row if there is no data for that week to sum (like 0 or NULL).

```
SELECT
    YEAR(Date) AS OrderYear,
    MONTH(Date) AS OrderMonth,
    SUM(Col1) AS SumCol1
FROM tb
GROUP BY
    GROUPING SETS
    (
        YEAR(Date), --1st grouping set
        (YEAR(Date),MONTH(Date)) --2nd grouping set
    )
```

Comment: Group totals in the middle of data like that is usually a presentation concern, e.g.: [group totals in SSRS reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/lesson-6-adding-grouping-and-totals-reporting-services).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

My solution uses the built in [`with rollup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) addition to the `group by` clause.

```
-- create sample data
declare @data table
(
    [Date] Date,
    WeekNo int,
    Col1 int,
    Col2 int,
    Col3 int
);

insert into @data ([Date], WeekNo, Col1, Col2, Col3) values
('2020-07-01', 27, 1, 4, 3),
('2020-07-04', 27, 3, 3, 1),
('2020-07-06', 28, 1, 1, 1),
('2020-07-11', 28, 1, 3, 8);

-- solution
select  case when grouping(d.Date) = 0
            then convert(nvarchar(10), d.Date) -- type conversion so all column values have the same type
            else 'TOTAL'
        end as 'Date',
        d.WeekNo,
        sum(d.Col1) as 'Col1',
        sum(d.Col2) as 'Col2',
        sum(d.Col3) as 'Col3'
from @data d
group by d.WeekNo, d.Date with rollup -- "roll up" the aggregations
having grouping(d.WeekNo) = 0; -- filter out aggregation across weeks
```

Gives me:

```
Date       WeekNo      Col1        Col2        Col3
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2020-07-01 27          1           4           3
2020-07-04 27          3           3           1
TOTAL      27          4           7           4
2020-07-06 28          1           1           1
2020-07-11 28          1           3           8
TOTAL      28          2           4           9
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need to add `(DATEPART(wk, Date))` as aggregation rule after listing the other non-aggregated columns `Date,Col1, Col2, Col3`. Btw, you do not need a `WeekNo` column, since it could already be computer by use of `(DATEPART(wk, Date))`.

So far so good, but ordering is such a daunting task as returning null values for WeekNo column for subtotal. I used two analytic functions ( `ROW_NUMBER()` and `FISRT_VALUE()` to overcome this problem ) :

```
SELECT COALESCE(Date,'TOTAL') As Date, 
       DATEPART(wk, Date) AS WeekNo,
       SUM(Col1) AS Col1,
       SUM(Col2) AS Col2,
       SUM(Col3) AS Col3                       
FROM tb
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( ( Date,Col1, Col2, Col3 ),
                           (DATEPART(wk, Date))        
                         )
ORDER BY CASE WHEN DATEPART(wk, Date) IS NULL 
              THEN
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(wk, Date)  
                              ORDER BY COALESCE(Date,'TOTAL') )
              ELSE
               DATEPART(wk, Date) -
               FIRST_VALUE(DATEPART(wk, Date)) 
                    OVER ( ORDER BY COALESCE(Date,'TOTAL') ) + 1               
              END,
         DATEPART(wk, Date)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da808af4531625795d58d5ae82c0baac)</kbd>